# Sort elements by document order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath

I have an array of `Element`s and I want them in document order. I know this is trivial to achieve in XPath, but the logic I have to implement is a bit complicated for a single expression.

I did find `Node.compareDocumentPosition()`, but it generates a bit mask of quite a few combinations, so not very ideal for a comparator.

As I final resort, I could probably add a random attribute on to all the elements in the array and select them again using XPath, but I'd rather not do that if possible.

Comment: how is the array built? is it a posability to build the array in document order intially rather then sort it after the event?

Comment: @atmd The elements are the results of some existing function calls. I can theoretically select them in document order, but the code won't look any better than the hacks I mentioned and adds unnecessary maintenance burden.

Comment: Just thinking aloud, maybe a brute force approach to reselect the elements from the document?  Depending on how you could determine an accurate selector for each (and only) element, you could run down the list and construct a selector to grab them all.  

In JQuery that might result in something like this:
$('#id20, #id5, #id12, #id7')... JQuery will return the set in document order, not in the order specified in the selector.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't necessarily agree that `document.compareDocumentPosition()` is insufficient for a comparator. Why do you consider this not ideal?

```js
var elementArray = [];

elementArray.push(document.getElementById('div3'));
elementArray.push(document.getElementById('div2'));
elementArray.push(document.getElementById('div4'));
elementArray.push(document.getElementById('div1'));

function documentPositionComparator (a, b) {
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  }

  var position = a.compareDocumentPosition(b);

  if (position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING || position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY) {
    return -1;
  } else if (position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING || position & Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }

}

console.log('unsorted::', elementArray);
console.log('sorted::', elementArray.sort(documentPositionComparator));
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1
  <div id="div2">Div 2
    <div id="div3">Div 3</div>
    <div id="div4">Div 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay. The code does not look as horrible as I thought it would be.